# Can't figure out how to add social media icons to a navigation/menu bar

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress site, using the wordpress theme flatsome http://flatsome.uxthemes.com/

I wish to add social media icons on the menu/navigation bar so that people can quickly go and access the different social media platforms.

please help!! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not that straight forward. Open the file header.php (I only guess that there should be the code for the nav bar), find the code snippet that produces the navigation bar and enhance it with your social media code.

If you find any trouble, post the part of the code that creates the nav bar to get a better look.